# Select Main class java

Tags: java

Por que cuando intento correr un archivo java me aparece esto? dice que espere pero nunca carga, ya intenté de todo y nada.
[image]

Comment: Has seleccionado un archivo Java Class, que no es lo mismo que un archico Main Class Java. Si seleccionas un archivo que puede ser "Run", debe tener en el icono el símbolo del play verde

Comment: De preferencia debes crear clases en mayúscula. Para correr el archivo deberías seleccionarla, clic derecho y darle run.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema ya lo desisntale y volvi a instalar y aun nada , no me deja correr el programa